# Java - Trying to remove certain elements from List<String>

Tags: java, string, list, remove-if

I'm trying to remove words starting with &, but the followning code gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
at java.util.Collection.removeIf(Collection.java:415)
at com.APT.SearchEngine.Main.main(Main.java:25)

String text="Hey &i love football";
List<String> purifiedList= Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));
purifiedList.removeIf((String word) -> word.startsWith("&"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList` returns an unmodifiable list.

Comment: That is not strictly true. The list allows `set` operaton, but not `add` and `remove`.

Comment: How can I allow remove please?

Comment: `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array))`